# linux fork() process issue

Tags: linux, fork

I have an issue with the following process as it is not running for some reason.

```
main()
{
  int n;
  for (n=0;n<10;n++)
  {
    printf("my pid = %d, my ppid = %d, n = %d\n" , getpid(), getppid(), n);
    sleep(1);
    if ( fork() != 0 )
      exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: How far do you get in the process of running it? What goes wrong?

Comment: It doesn't run - I get an error on line 4 (the loop)

Comment: Right, I understand that it doesn't run. My question is how far do you get in the process of running it. And you didn't answer that. You get an error on line 4 when you try to do what? Compile it? Link it? Execute it? When it starts running? And what error?

Comment: `main()` where is the return type? Which programming language is that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to execute it on an online shell and I get the following error "could not parse this for loop". Thank you

Comment: Which "shell"? Where have you seen this code that you are copying?

Comment: @Filburt I am confused. Why did you do that?

Comment: Ok, remove the "sleep(1)", replace "!= 0" by "!= 1", compile it with a C compiler and try again to run it. Then can you say if it still replies with an error ? That may help.

Comment: Online bash shell. I wrote it and I would like to see if it works or if there are any errors?

Comment: Please show how you are compiling the file, and please show how you are attempting to run the file. When the run fails, please show the error message. There are three actionable items for you. Please *edit* your question and supply the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is C code that needs to be compiled and executed. It's not shell code and it won't run in a shell.

Comment: I compiled it using gcc and ran it using ./fork and it worked!